# Existence of unitary operator affecting partial trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

Let $\rho$ and $\phi$ be *any* two different density matrices on $H_A \otimes H_B$ such that $Tr_B (\rho) = Tr_B (\phi)$.

Does there always exist a unitary $U$ on $H_A \otimes H_B$, $U\rho U^{\dagger} = \rho^{\prime}$ and $U\phi U^{\dagger} = \phi^{\prime}$ such that $Tr_B (\rho^{\prime}) \neq Tr_B (\phi^{\prime})$?

Comment: First of all, note that users are expected to provide context, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In other words, users are discouraged both from asking and answering questions where the asker has not shown proof of some amount of effort put into the problem. Can you tell us what you've tried? Have you tried looking for small counterexamples, for instance?

Comment: Second, the question is a bit strange. Unless I am mistaken, it looks like taking $U$ to be the identity matrix always produces the desired result. Does that answer your question, or do you have some unstated restriction that would rule out the solution $U = I$?

Comment: You might find it a bit more interesting that every transformation of the form $U = I_{A} \otimes V$ for some unitary $V$ over $\mathcal H_B$ would also work

Comment: There was a typo in the question, the reduced states of the transformed $\rho$ and $\phi$ should not be equal. Hence, I want to prove that, for any two different states with same reduced states (of A), I can always define a unitary that maps them to other states with different reduced states.

Comment: The question definitely makes sense now. If you were willing to edit your question to address the first comment, I’d be happy to leave an answer

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will later edit the question giving details of my current approach.

Comment: As a sort of trivial statement: if $\dim\mathcal H_A = 1$ and $\dim \mathcal H_B > 1$, then (since the partial trace over $B$ is simply the trace) it's clear that no such $U$ can exist

Comment: A potentially helpful way of reframing the problem: this is equivalent to asking whether $\operatorname{tr}_B(U(\rho - \phi)U^\dagger) = 0$ for all $U$ implies that $\rho - \phi = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a detailed look at the case where $\mathcal H_A = \mathcal H_B = \Bbb C^2$. A similar line of reasoning is applicable whenever both $\mathcal H_A,\mathcal H_B$ have dimension greater than $1$.

Let $\sigma = \rho - \phi \neq 0$. For a proof by contrapositive, we will show that if $\operatorname{tr}_B(U\sigma U^\dagger) = 0$ for all $U$, then $\sigma = 0$ (and hence $\rho = \varphi$). Note that $\sigma$ is Hermitian, and hence unitarily diagonalizable. That is, there exists a $U$ such that
$$
U\sigma U^\dagger = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ & &\lambda_3 \\ &&& \lambda_4}.
$$
The partial trace computation yields $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 = 0$. However, a permutation matrix $P$ allows us to obtain diagonal matrices $(PU)\sigma(PU)^\dagger$ with the eigenvalues permuted arbitrarily. Thus, we have $\lambda_i + \lambda_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$.

To conclude that the eigenvalues are all zero, we could apply logic like the following:
$$
\lambda_1 = -\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = -\lambda_1 \implies \lambda_1 = 0.
$$
Thus, $\sigma$ is a Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues equal to zero. Thus, $\sigma = 0$, which was what we wanted.

So, in the case that $\mathcal H_A = \mathcal H_B = \Bbb C^2$, we indeed find that such a $U$ must exist whenever $\rho \neq \phi$.

This argument can easily be extended to allow us to conclude that such a $U$ must exist in the case where $\dim(\mathcal H_B) = 2$ and $\dim(\mathcal H_A) \geq 2$ is arbitrary.

---

In fact, the above argument can be extended to handle the general case where $\dim(\mathcal H_A) > 1$. Let $m,n$ denote the dimensions of $\mathcal H_A, \mathcal H_B$ respectively. The matrix $\sigma = \rho - \phi$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_{mn}$. Using suitable matrices $U$, we can conclude that for any distinct indices $j_1,\dots,j_n$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_{j_k} = 0.
$$
With that, we have
$$
\lambda_1 + \sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \lambda_k = \lambda_2 + \sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \lambda_k = 0 \implies\\
\left(\lambda_1 + \sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \lambda_k\right) - \left(\lambda_2 + \sum_{k=3}^{n+1} \lambda_k\right) = 0 \implies\\
\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 = 0.
$$
That is, we have $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$. By a similar argument, $\lambda_j = \lambda_k$ for all $1 \leq j,k \leq mn$. On the other hand, the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(\sigma) = 0$ implies that
$$
\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_{mn} = mn \lambda_1 = 0 \implies \lambda_1 = 0,
$$
so that all eigenvalues of $\sigma$ are equal to zero. Since $\sigma$ is a Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues are equal to zero, we conclude that $\sigma = 0$, as desired.